# Simple JSON to CSV in MS Power Automate problem

Tags: flow, power-automate, json, csv, ms-flow

I am trying to convert the following JSON using the URL: https://api0.solar.sheffield.ac.uk/pvlive/v3/pes/0 to CSV vis MS Power Automate.

I use HTTP to get the response from above URL.

And this is where it goes wrong. I Parse the JSON using the following:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "array"
            }
        },
        "meta": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which then I pass onto a CSV table which needs an array not an object.

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as well when I selected "Body" as the input for the create csv step.  The Body is an object, but there should be a "Results" array for you to select.  Use "Results" as your input and it should work as intended.